# JMeter- Sending one email for multiple http responses

Tags: jmeter, email

[image: Screenshot for Groovy is attached][image]I am using csv for http requests and sending emails in case of failure. Can I send only one email at the end of http requests from csv file. Like if 10 http request failed then I want to send a single email containing urls of all pages for which response was 404 or a failure response returned by server. Image Attached

Comment: can you share the structure of your test plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it simple and moved SMTP Sample under tearDown ThreadGroup and attached Aggregate Report with Email which contains all information which I want to send in email.
Also In Aggregate Report I selected option that show only Errors which made this report more concise.

Thanks for Answers. @Dmitri T

If anyone having issue feel free to consult.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to the main Thread Group
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
       def failures = props.get("failures")
       if (failures != null) {
           builder.append(failures)
       }
       builder.append(prev.getUrlAsString())
       builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
       props.put("failures", builder.toString());
   }
   ```
3. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) with 1 virtual user and 1 loop to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
4. Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to this tearDown Thread Group
5. Use `${__groovy(props.get("failures") != null,)}` as the If Controller's condition
6. Put your [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) as a child of the if controller
7. Use `${__P(failures,)}` in the mail body - it will hold failed samplers URLs.

Assuming above configuration JMeter will send only one email with the list of all failed samplers URLs and only if any sampler has failed. Feel free to amend the code as required.

References:

- [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
- [__groovy() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi Thanks,

Following Error shown in logs:

2017/05/11 14:32:06 ERROR - jmeter.control.IfController: IF Condition: error while processing [${__groovy(props.get("failures") != null,)}]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)

Can you please explain this -> 
${__groovy(props.get("failures") != null,)}

As response code returned in case of failure is 404 and I want to match that.

Comment: Make sure you are using **Groovy** as language in the JSR223 Sampler, it looks like for some reason you trying JavaScript

Comment: Just following written in 
Condition(default javascript): ${__groovy(props.get("failures") != null,)}

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice you are sitting on JMeter 3.0 and __groovy() function was introduced in [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31). You either need to upgrade your JMeter or revert to i.e. [__Beanshell function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell): `${__BeanShell(props.get("failures") != null)}`